# How can i show images to limited users in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I want to show my post to my followers only how can I implement that here is my code.

here is the structure of my user collection[image]

here is the collection of posts by user [image]

```
  final model.User userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;

StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(post_collection)
              .orderBy("datePublished",
                  descending:
                      true) 
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    PostCard(snap: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()));
          }),
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: What details should i provide??

Comment: We need to understand what the trouble is with your code.  Does it crash? What part doesn't work? Can you tell us what troubleshooting you've done? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

My logic to approach this problem would be:

1. If I am a user, I should be able to see the post of people I follow, so the source of posts that are visible to me would arrive only from the list of people I follow. Create this list as an attribute of users in their database record. Every time the user follows someone, that someone is added to this list.
2. So if you want your posts to be seen only by your followers, as soon as someone follows you, your account would be added to the list of people they follow. Thus your account becomes just another source of accounts from which that particular follower receives post updates from.
3. You could implement the logic to receive posts only from the list of people a particular user follows. This way only your followers will be able to see your posts.

Comment: Can you provide some code rough code that would help a lot better..

Comment: How about mapping each post to my followers??

Comment: I will try to share something tomorrow, and mapping each post to your followers feels incomplete because what would happen if a new follower joins after you have posted something? Will he be able to see your previous post because you didn't map that new follower in your post as he didn't join at the time.